# Neo4j from Python in Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, neo4j

I would like to use Neo4j from Python in Windows 7 operating system. Which library can I install? Py2Neo seems to work for Linux and Mac but not for Windows.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We are always happy to see you here, but with better and _on-topic_ questions. This question doesn't show any effort you've put into it. For example, _how exactly doesn't `py2neo` work on Windows_? Any errors/error messages? Furthermore, your question might be slightly [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. You should clarify it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

py2Neo is a library which you can generate/configure/manipulate Neo4j graph database. It is not an executable application. As far as your Python works on Windows, py2neo should work as well. You can download py2neo via pip install as you can download many libraries as well.